# simplify functions in Quickgraph and good documentation?

Tags: algorithm, quickgraph

I'm figuring out whether Quickgraph is beneficial for my problems (F# project). Does it have graph reduction functions/algorithms? Similar to Matlab's [simplify functions](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.simplify.html).

Furthermore, I'm having troubles with finding architectural documentation (principals and data structure) of Quickgraph and tutorials for a flying start. The same goes for the BoostGraph where it seems to be ported from. Any suggestions?

Regards, WP

Comment: Just google for `quickgraph`. The very first results are the (archived, Codeplex) repo and docs, and link to the NuGet package. This is a *very* old library though that wasn't even migrated to Github when Codeplex shut down. Lots of clones though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos tnx. I did clone it for the source code and install it with nuget. Documentation is still limited. I ended up plowing through the test code to figure out how to use it. Not my preferred way, though.

Comment: it's an abandoned project. There are other libraries for what you want. Did you check what's available in NuGet ?

Comment: I found a repo that still had some commits not ridiculously long ago, if I remember correctly. I have chosen this one since it based on the boost graph lib which seems to be a widely accepted lib.

Comment: Excuse me for the separate messages. The gui of the app is a bit confusion and inconsistent. Most libs I found are either for visualization or have similarly lack of documentation. Since you’re so convinced that there are well documented libs in nuget I’ll give it go again. If you happen to know one then I’m very interested in it.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but thought I'd share this for future readers since the QuickGraph page on CodePlex now only has broken links.

Documentation from Dec 2017 can be found [here (web archive for QuickGraph)](http://web.archive.org/web/20171224093024/http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/documentation).

It might not be completely up-to-date with the latest source code, but it can contains a nice overview of graph types and algorithms.